# DataGrab Error: "Cannot open file/url" only on production server

Tags: xml, datagrab

I'm having an issue similar to this:
http://brandnewbox.co.uk/forums/viewthread/644/

I'm getting "Error: Cannot open file/url" when I try to configure an XML import. I'm building an XML feed with an EE template and then trying to access it Datagrab via a URL. This works for me locally but not on the production server.

If I save an XML file, upload it to my server and then get Datagrab to access thru the server file path, it works fine. I just can access from a URL.

Andrew Weaver mentions in the thread above that PHP might be configured to not allow files to be read over http. Any idea how I could change this setting? Is this something I could fix in a php.ini or .htaccess file?

Any idea what's going on here? Or if there's a more descriptive error I could find by enabling a debug more or looking in a log file?

The problem started when I upgraded from v1.5.0 to v1.7.5. I'm also on a Media Temple grid server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the simple solution to this. I just needed to add this line to my .htaccess file to allow PHP to access files across http.

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

Comment: We have the same issue, oddly : <code>php_value allow_url_fopen On
</code> is set to on